# WPF Adding a 'Resource' Project to a solution with multiple WPF applications

Tags: wpf, fonts, project-structure

I am developing three kiosk-like applications in WPF. They will share a similar look and feel, and I was hoping to create the projects all in the same solution. What I would like to do is add a project to the solution that just holds shared resources, such as fonts and images.

My question is, is it possible to share resources like embedded fonts across applications, and if so, what is the appropriate project type for this use? (class library? WPF user control?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a WPF Custom Control Library, then create a ResourceDictionary to hold the resources, where in the App.xaml of your start-up project I would link the Resource dictionary.

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/myResourceLibrary;component/myResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

That way, you can just move the DLL around to whichever solution you want to use it in.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a good way to do it. I'm going to mark this an answer if something better doesn't pop up today. For now I've upvoted.

Comment: went ahead and implemented this for my custom styles and fonts. Seems to be a quick solution and now I don't need the same style defined 3 different times.